# Programmatically Change Android USB Host Auto Launch

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

To get an activity to automatically launch when a specified USB device is connected, the following intent and corresponding meta data can be added to the activity in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```

However, in my app, I have a settings tab where I want to give the user the option to enable or disable auto launch. How can I programmatically reconfigure the manifest to this behavior on user request?